# How to extend journal file size of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

Is there any way to extend **journal file size limit** of wiredtiger engine inside of MongoDB?
I found several ways to adjust the journal file size, but they introduced the way to vary the size smaller, not larger.
([How to control size of journals in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632566/how-to-control-size-of-journals-in-mongodb)
[MongoDB Journal File Size - Relation to Data File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549992/mongodb-journal-file-size-relation-to-data-file-size) )
The target journal file size what I want to change is, `20GiB`.
If it is impossible in MongoDB, adjusting wiredtiger engine code is also welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Journal files hold data that has not yet been written to the data files, which occurs at least once per minute.  Are you trying to stop data from being written to the data files, or are you trying to keep the journal files around after the data has been committed?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/#journaling) mentions a 100MB limit _per file_, but doesn't say the overall amount of data is limited.  I suppose if you managed to write 20GB of data in between checkpoints, the journal would grow to hold it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The reason I want to hold journal file is, to stop data from being written to the data file. I think the period of flushing to the disk from memory would be longer if the file of journal has been increased.

Comment: No, checkpoints happen on a schedule, and the journal will grow as large as it needs to hold the data in between.  There is the [syPeriodSecs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.syncPeriodSecs) configuration that might help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Then, what about committing period, not checkpoint period? Is it able to control committing, which flush data to disk from central log buffer which is located in main memory?

Comment: The checkpoint is what flushes data to the data files.